# Connect SQL Server database to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I want to connect a SQL Server database by using `pgAdmin4`. I already have data in the SQL Server database and want to connect this database in PostgreSQL. I have tried with foreign data also but not working.

If anyone knows the solution it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions that I've used:

### **Solution 1:** `tds_fdw`

You can install `tds_fdw` that is a foreign data wrapper to MSSQL to postgreSQL and, with this foreign data wrapper, you can use your MSSQL tables and schemas as foreign tables inside postgresql. More details [here](https://github.com/tds-fdw/tds_fdw).

As you not provisioned which OS you are using, is better to se inside the project and apply as your needs.

### **Solution 2:** [Apache Kafka and Debezium](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.1/connectors/sqlserver.html)

A little bit complicated than installing a `fdw`, you can do a streaming replication enabling CDC on MSSQL Server and collecting via Debezium the tables that you need and real-time replicating to you PostgreSQL database connecting via JDBC so, you need what is your scenario and decide what is the best option.

Comment: i am using windows os for both server.

Comment: can some one help me urgently!!

Answer (score 0):

`tds_fdw` is good, but maybe you should find the windows install package.

Otherwise, if you just want to use one tool that you can query data from both Databases, you should try **[dbeaver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBeaver) or [navicat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navicat)**.